# Exporting a windows form using database in c# to an application

Tags: c#, database

I'm working on a project using c# with database (a WinForms application).

I tried to use the `.exe` file in the Release directory but when I copy it to another folder on my computer, or use it on another one, it says it can't find the `.mdf` file (Database).

How can I export the project as an application so the database will exist?

Comment: have you tried copying said .mdf file with your project?

Comment: Did you move the entire Release directory? It also sounds like you're using the AttachDb option so you'll need to move it along with the EXE (get the path from the connection string in App.config) and you may even need to change the connection string in your app config file (ProgramName.exe.config).

Comment: You could also create the database in code if it doesn't exist already. Then you dont have to distribute the database with the application.

Comment: I moved the entire Realease directory. And thank you, I`ll try to what you told me to.